# Li elements overflowing out of my Navigation bar (html)

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit new to HTML/CSS and I'm having some trouble with creating properly positioning elements inside my navigation bar.

My `li` elements are overflowing out of the bar.

This is my code atm:

HTML

```
<body class="body">
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="pull-left">
        <a href="#home"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#news"><li>News</li></a>
        <a href="#about"><li>About</li></a>
    </ul>

    <ul class="pull-right">
        <a href="#login"><li>Login</li></a>
        <a href="#signup"><li>Sign Up</li></a>
        <a href="#support"><li>Support</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">

</div>
```

CSS

```
    .body {
    border: solid red 3px;
    margin: 0px
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    border:3px solid green;
    display:block;
}

.navbar ul{
    display:inline;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar ul li{
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: -6px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #0099FF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li:hover{
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg');
    height: 600px;
}

.pull-left {
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.pull-right {
    float:right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e36oqsqs/)

How do I make my buttons stay inside the navbar and expand it automatically?
I looked through a lot of similar posts and tried a couple of things, however I couldn't quite get it to work.

Comment: First things first height of class navbar is 25px, so is it mandatory?

Comment: @divy3993 forgot to remove that again I see. Was just trying to adjust it manually, however I would like it to be done automatically.

Comment: So not necessary right?

Comment: I think below answer is what you looking for.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you **must specify overflow** property.

Here you must specify `overflow:auto;` with `height:auto;`(optional as it's default even if not specified)

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    border:3px solid green;
    display:block;
    height:auto /* Not mandatory as is default if not specifed */ 
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e36oqsqs/8/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying with overflow at one moment but was probably placing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Html file is this

<body class="body">

    <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="pull-left">
        <a href="#home"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#news"><li>News</li></a>
        <a href="#about"><li>About</li></a>
    </ul>

    <ul class="pull-right">
        <a href="#login"><li>Login</li></a>
        <a href="#signup"><li>Sign Up</li></a>
        <a href="#support"><li>Support</li></a>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">

</div>

</body>

Css is this

.body {
    border: solid red 3px;
    margin: 0px
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    border:3px solid green;
    display:block;
    /*height:25px;*/
}

.navbar ul{
    display:inline;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar ul li{
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: -6px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #0099FF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.navbar ul li:hover{
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg');
    height: 600px;
}

.pull-left {
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.pull-right {
    float:right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.clearBoth{clear: both;}
```

Comment: In html file I have mention this

<div class="clearBoth"></div>

Comment: and css file I have change on 
.navbar {
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    border:3px solid green;
    display:block;
    /*height:25px;*/
}

.clearBoth{clear: both;}